# ¿Cómo modificar el Header de una petición en Node.js?

Tags: nodejs

¿Cómo modificar la cabecera de una petición en Node.js antes de enviarla?

```
 res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  'ETag': '1234532323232323232323'
});
res.redirect(sitionweb);
```

Probé con eso pero cuando miro la petición con `console.log(req)`
no aparece las modificaciones que hice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Esto es lo que buscàs?

```
res.writeHead(statusCode, {header: value, header: value});
```

Por ejemplo:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
   'content-type': 'text/html'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Modificas tu Header con el contenido de un html externo de la siguiente manera:

Index.js

```
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');
http.createServer(function(request,response)
{
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/leer_html.html',function(error,content){
        response.write(content);
         response.end();
    });
}).listen(6969,function(){
console.log("Servidor Corriendo.... Puerto 6969");
});
```

y tu archivo leer_html.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Node Js</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Bienvenido Humano</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```